# How can i get back information wiped off my Iphone by accidental restore?

Tags: ios, data-synchronization, iphone, restore

I plugged in my iPhone to attempt to sync so that I could update my software.  The sync was not working.  I looked up problem on internet and they suggested that I restore the settings on the iPhone.  I followed the directions.  When I did so the phone rebooted and I lost everything (contacts, calendar, photos).  Is there any way to recover this information?

Comment: Have you ever backed up said iPhone? Either via direct cable sync via iTunes or via iCloud?

Comment: no the sync through i tunes only backed up the applications not the contacts or calendar.  I did not realize that I needed to do something to make it back up contacts

Comment: Well restoration from a backup is really your only choice. Who is your email provider? If Google there is a chance they would have copies of said contacts.